# Objectify doesn't always return results

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am using Objectify to store data on Google App Engine's datastore. I have been trying to implement a one-to-many relationship between two classes, but by storing a list of parameterised keys. The method below works perfectly some of the time, but returns an empty array other times - does anyone know why this may be?

It will either return the correct list of CourseYears, or

```
{
 "items": [
 ]
}
```

Here is the method:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getCourseYears") @ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
public ArrayList<CourseYear> getCourseYears(@Named("name") String name){

    Course course = ofy().load().type(Course.class).filter("name", name).first().now();
    System.out.println(course.getName());

    ArrayList<CourseYear> courseYears = new ArrayList<CourseYear>();
    for(Key<CourseYear> courseYearKey: course.getCourseYears()){
        courseYears.add(ofy().load().type(CourseYear.class).id(courseYearKey.getId()).now());
    }

    return courseYears;
}
```

The Course class which stores many CourseYear keys

```
@Entity
public class Course {
@Id
@Index
private Long courseId;

private String code;

@Index
private String name;

@ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
public List<Key<CourseYear>> getCourseYears() {
    return courseYears;
}

@ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
public void setCourseYears(List<Key<CourseYear>> courseYears) {
    this.courseYears = courseYears;
} 

@ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
     public void addCourseYear(Key<CourseYear> courseYearRef){
    courseYears.add(courseYearRef);
}
@Load
@ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
List<Key<CourseYear>> courseYears = new ArrayList<Key<CourseYear>>();

...

}
```

I am debugging this on the debug server using the API explorer. I have found that it will generally work at the start for a few times but if I leave and return to the API and try and run it again, it will not start working again after that.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to reduce the amount of queries you send to the datastore. Try something like this:

```
Course course = ofy().load().type(Course.class).filter("name", name).first().now();

ArrayList<CourseYear> courseYears = new ArrayList<CourseYear>();
List<Long> courseIds = new List<>();
for(Key<CourseYear> courseYearKey: course.getCourseYears()){
    courseIds.add(courseYearKey.getId());
}
Map<Long, Course> courses = ofy().load().type(CourseYear.class).ids(courseIds).list();
// add all courses from map to you courseYears list
```

I also strongly recommend a change in your data structure / entities:

In your CourseYears add a property `Ref<Course> courseRef` with the parent Course and make it indexed (`@Index`). Then query by

```
ofy().load().type(CourseYear.class).filter("courseRef", yourCourseRef).list();
```

This way you'll only require a single query.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have realised that I may not be maintaining the list of keys/references correctly - is the following code enough to maintain the list?

    Ref<CourseYear> key = Ref.create(courseYear);
    course.addCourseYear(key);

Comment: You obviously have a background in relational databases. With cloud datastore you sometimes have to think backwards. Do not try to apply your normalization rules to datastore, think about what you want to query for and what the most efficient query would look like. Then design your entities accordingly. You should not maintain a list of keys at all, the list would be serialized in the datastore and you couldn't filter a query by the list or its content. Add a Ref (foreign key) to your decendant (n) entity and query by that Ref.

Comment: I think I've got it working! I've tried what you've described in the past but it really clicked the way you described it. Thank you so much, I've been struggling and stressing over this a lot and it's all sorted now!

Answer (score 0):

The two most likely candidates are:

1. Eventual consistency behavior of the high replication datastore. Queries (ie your filter() operation) always run a little behind because indexes propagate through GAE asynchronously. See the GAE docs.
2. You haven't installed the `ObjectifyFilter`. Read the setup guide. Recent versions of Objectify throws an error if you haven't installed it, so if you're on the latest version, this isn't it.